# Constant reference data member

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's suppose we have a structure with a constant reference data member.

```
struct A {
    A() : i{5} {}
    const int& foo() const { return i; }
    const int& i;
};
```

Do you have any idea why the output for an integer literal 5 is different?

```
A a{};
std::cout << a.i << std::endl;
std::cout << a.foo() << std::endl;

5
-858993460
```

Comment: I get a [compiler warning](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/h5JLk_) for this. Clang actually gives an error. Are you asking why this isn't correct, or specifically why the two outputs are different knowing the program is incorrect?

Comment: See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d0bd763cebcbd04) also. Looks like you have a case of _undefined behavior_.

Comment: BTW, VS 2017 doesn't output any warnings. I don't understand why an integer literal goes out of the scope only when accessing the referenced value in function foo.

Comment: @dubrava UB means anything is possible; so you might get the result of `5`,  `-858993460`, or `42`, or something else like segfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is ill-formed. You're initializing `i` from literal `5`, which requires a temporary object to be contructed and then bound to `i`. The temporary will be destroyed when the constructor exits, then `i` becomes dangled, any dereference on it later leads to UB, means anything is possible.

From the standard, [[class.base.init]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#8)

> A temporary expression bound to a reference member in a
>   mem-initializer is ill-formed. [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   A() : v(42) { }   // error
>   const int& v;
> };
> ```
>
> — end example ]

BTW: Since the standard states it's *ill-formed*, the compilers are required to issue a diagnostic for it. Both the behavior of gcc (gives a warning) and clang (gives an error) are conforming; if VS2017 doesn't issue any diagnostic then it's non-conforming to the standard.

Comment: OK, thank you for the reference and detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Use of a `constant` value not a `literal`.

This is  `Class::Class() : member{arg1, arg2, ...} {...`  direct-list-initialization since `c++11`.

Try this :

```
 struct A {
    const int t = 5;
    A() : i{ t } { }
    const int& foo() const { return i; }
    const int& i;
};

int main()
{
    A a{};
    std::cout << a.i << std::endl;
    std::cout << a.foo() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't mean to store a temporary literal, just was wondering if its scope is a class or constructor.

Comment: @dubrava I improved my answer, please check it. But about your question, honestly i didnt work with c++11 but I offered this answer to solving your problem . by the way [this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) might help you.

Comment: If I'd like to initialize the const reference to default value, I'd use in-class initializer  const int& i {5};